# Draw rectangles on an image in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figure out how to draw rectangles on an image in Matlab.

Once the rectangles are drawn on the image I would like to save the changes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`getframe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html)

```
img = imread('cameraman.tif');
fh = figure;
imshow( img, 'border', 'tight' ); %//show your image
hold on;
rectangle('Position', [50 70 30 60] ); %// draw rectangle on image
frm = getframe( fh ); %// get the image+rectangle
imwrite( frm.cdata, 'savedFileName.png' ); %// save to file
```

See [`rectanlge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) for more options on drawing rectangles. The `'Position'` argument for rectangle is in format `[from_x from_y width height]` and is given in units of pixels.

Comment: What if the image is too large fitting the screen ? is there a way to keep the original image resolution ?

Comment: @ShmilTheCat I suppose you can set `'Position'` propety of the figure `fh`: `set(fh, 'Position', [0 0 size(img,2), size(img,1)])`?

Answer (score 3):

Without using getframe:

```
im=imread('face.jpg'); %Image read
rectangle('Position', [10 10 30 30] ,...
    'EdgeColor', 'r',...
    'LineWidth', 3,...
    'LineStyle','-');%rectangle properties
imshow( im, rectangle); %draw rectangle on image.
```

For more detail visit [this MathWorks thread](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/110230-drawing-a-rectangle-on-top-of-an-image) :)

Answer (score 2):

The best and easy way to use is in the updated Matlab versions

```
img = imread('abcd.jpg');
box = [X1, Y1, width, height];    
outImage= insertObjectAnnotation(img,'rectangle',bbox,'Rectangle');
figure, imshow(outImage), title('Image with rectangle');
```

Comment: This requires the "ComputerVision" toolbox?

Answer (score 0):

I am using `octave` and the function `getframe` is not available so i wrote this trivial function

```
%% Draw red rectangle IN the image using the BoundingBox from regionprops
function rgbI = drawRectangleOnImg (box,rgbI)
    x = box(2); y = box(1); w = box(4); h = box(3);
    rgbI(x:x+w,y,1)   = 255;
    rgbI(x:x+w,y+h,1) = 255;
    rgbI(x,y:y+h,1)   = 255;
    rgbI(x+w,y:y+h,1) = 255;
    rgbI(x:x+w,y,2)   = 0;
    rgbI(x:x+w,y+h,2) = 0;
    rgbI(x,y:y+h,2)   = 0;
    rgbI(x+w,y:y+h,2) = 0;
    rgbI(x:x+w,y,3)   = 0;
    rgbI(x:x+w,y+h,3) = 0;
    rgbI(x,y:y+h,3)   = 0;
    rgbI(x+w,y:y+h,3) = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 I=imread('%required image');   
[M,N] = size(rgb2gray(I));%find the size of the image
x=int16(M/3);y=int16(N/3);xwidth=int16(N/3); ywidth=int16(N/3);%specify the position
pos=[x y xwidth ywidth];% give the position in which you wanna insert the rectangle
imshow(I);hold on
rectangle('Position',pos,'EdgeColor','b')
```